# python iteratively deleting dictionaries with key value

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

If I wanted to iterate over a group of dictionaries, deleting all dictionaries where the value of a certain key was zero, how could I do that?
I originally tried the code below, but that obviously doesn't work in many cases, as the length of the group decreases as objects are deleted.

```
data = [{'symbol': 'AA', 'sum': 0}, {'symbol': 'BB', 'sum': 0}, {'symbol': 'CC', 'sum': 10}]

for i in range (0, len(data)):
        if data[i]["sum"] == 0:
            del data[i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a good idea to delete elements from a list while you go over the list.

A much pythonic solution will be:

```
data = [{'symbol': 'AA', 'sum': 0}, {'symbol': 'BB', 'sum': 0}, {'symbol': 'CC', 'sum': 10}]
data = [x for x in data if x['sum'] != 0]
```

This way we create a list based on all of the items we already have in `data` if the item['sum'] != 0